# "error:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)"unhandled exception: type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'list<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Working with Get and FCM. Am passing List of Class Model Get and when i print it it's List am sure. And When am getting data am getting it in the same Class Model and same List, and also when i print it it's a List too, but am still getting the error shown in the title. i tried casting to List and to List but nothing seems to work.

```
void sendOrder(OrderModel order) async {
    await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=$serverToken'
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        'notification': <String, dynamic>{
          'title': 'New Order',
          'body': order.name
        },
        'priority': 'high',
        'data': <String, dynamic>{
          'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
          'name': order.name,
          'phone': order.phone,
          'meds': order.medicines,
          'token': order.orderToken
        },
        'to': '/topics/pharmacy'
      }),
    );
  }
```

```
class OrderModel {
  String name;
  String phone;
  List medicines = [];
  String orderToken;

  OrderModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.phone,
    required this.medicines,
    required this.orderToken,
  });

  factory OrderModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return OrderModel(
      name: map['name'] ?? "",
      phone: map['phone'] ?? "",
      medicines: map['medicines'] ?? "",
      orderToken: map['orderToken'] ?? "",
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "phone": phone,
      "medicines": medicines,
      "orderToken": orderToken,
    };
  }
}
```

```
getMessage() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      Get.snackbar("New Order", message.data['name']);
      OrderModel order = OrderModel(
        name: message.data['name'] ?? '',
        phone: message.data['phone'] ?? '',
        medicines: message.data['meds'] ?? [],
        orderToken: message.data['token'] ?? '',
      );
      usersOrders.add(order);
    });
    update();
  }
```

Comment: can you attach the data you are getting?

Comment: It's possible that the "medicines" field values are coming as a string not as a list as you expect here.

Comment: u mean when i print the gotten data in console ?

Comment: but am printing it and every time it pritns get list also am sending list and receiving it in list. what can i do to solve it or prevent it from happening ?